# Dynamic return types with PEP 484

Tags: python, type-hinting, pep

Say I have a function that will return a class based on a string input parameter, like so:

```
def foo(bar):
    if bar == 'baz':
        return Baz()
    else:
        return Buz()
```

In this case, both `Baz` and `Buz` are subclasses of `Biz`, but each has a number of distinct functions, so declaring the return type as the superclass is not particularly useful. Assuming I don't care if my `.pyi` file is hideous, is there any way for me to declare what subclass is returned for a given input?

Comment: Every variable is dynamically typed in Python, so if you really need to know what type a variable is, use `type(...)`. Like, `type("example string") == str` will be `True`.

Comment: I understand that, my purposes here are to provide IDE support for this method and the classes it returns.

Comment: https://github.com/ambv/typehinting and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can quite that specifically, what you can do though is declare that something returns two different types like so:

```
from typing import Union

class Bar:
    pass
class Baz:
    pass

def foo(garply : str) -> Union[Bar, Baz]:
    pass
```

Take a look at the docs here:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types

And a reasonable short overview here: 
http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/

You might be better off thinking how to avoid this questionable design rather than how to perfectly document it with type hints.

Comment: I appreciate the help! This might be a possibility. This design is a result of auto-generating classes at runtime, so there's not much to be done to avoid it.

Comment: I suppose if you're generating things at runtime (or if not, even!) the obvious way to clearly couple an input to a specific type of output is to have a separate function. It almost sounds like you want the type hints to describe semantics and they probably won't work too well for that.