# How to set a class method return typing dynamically from a class property

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm working in a pet project of mine and found this little issue. I want to use typings withtin a base class, the problem is that the return type of the class methods are defined by a field set by the subclasses. Here is my base class

```
class BaseRepository(metaclass=RequiredAttributes('model')):

    model = None  # The subclasses have to define the this field with a class type.
                  # All the class methods will return objects of the same
                  # type as this field.

    def get(self, id) -> ??:
        # return an object of the type defined in mode
        ...


class UserRepo(BaseRepository): # subclass

    model = User # class type

    ...
```

I want to set the typing for the `get` function to be the same object type as defined in the model field.

Any suggestion on how can I acomplish something like that?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907714/dynamic-return-types-with-pep-484

Comment: You might want to look into `typing.TypeVar`. It can be used to indicate that within a given scope, multiple variables share the same type. You can do `T = TypeVar("T")`, then have `-> T:` as the return type. Unfortunately, type hinting class attributes makes the variable an instance attribute, so that will complicate matters a bit.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Did you forget about [`typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I annotate the type of a parameter of an abstractmethod, when the parameter can have any type derived from a specific base type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167179/how-do-i-annotate-the-type-of-a-parameter-of-an-abstractmethod-when-the-paramet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the metaclass, this [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=885b4c6d9a5451b3f192d53b34a9bfc6), which is correctly able to infer that `x` is of type `User`. I wasn't able to test it with the metaclass, as I don't have your metaclass definition. The solution uses a parameterised `Generic` as a base class, which allows you to then assert to the type-checker that different methods across the class will have the same parameter and return argument types. A similar technique is used in Django's [stub files](https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs/blob/8ba53c7db451e50aec86d51baafecf9b2315c90e/rest_framework-stubs/serializers.pyi#L214).

N.B. You'll have to import `Type` from the `typing` module and use `Optional[Type[M]]` instead of `Optional[type[M]]` for your `model` annotation if you're using Python <= 3.8.

```
from typing import Optional, Generic, TypeVar


M = TypeVar('M')


class BaseRepository(Generic[M], metaclass=RequiredAttributes('model')):
    model: Optional[type[M]] = None     # The subclasses have to define the this field with a class type.
                                        # All the class methods will return objects of the same
                                        # type as this field.

    def get(self, id: int) -> M: ...
        # return an object of the type defined in mode
        

class User:
    pass


class UserRepo(BaseRepository[User]): # subclass
    model = User # class type
    

x = UserRepo().get(1)
reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is "__main__.User*"
```