# How can I auto-complete python code if i use dynamic type

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is an example below:

```py
class Service:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def get(self, clazz):
        # clazz is a class Type, and always return an instance of clazz
        return self.data[clazz]

    def register(self, clazz, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data[clazz] = clazz(*args, **kwargs)

class A:
    def method_of_a(self):
        pass

class B:
    pass

service = Service()
service.register(A)
service.register(B)
```

now I complete the code of service, and continue coding like

```py
x = service.get(A)
x.method_of_a()
```

the code works, but there is a problem, when i was coding, the IDE(pycharm in this case) will not show the function of x when you input

```
x.
```

even i modify my code like this, it does'nt work

```py
def get(self, clazz):
    result: clazz = self.data[clazz]
    return result
```

I want to know if there any way to implement Service, that IDE can recognise the type of the return value?

Comment: Typehint your code: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Related: [How to set a class method return typing dynamically from a class property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68818915/8746648)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `typing.TypeVar` and `typing.Type` to type-hint your `.get()` function to say "if called with the type of T, this returns an instance of T":

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')


class Service:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def get(self, clazz: Type[T]) -> T:
        return self.data[clazz]

    def register(self, clazz, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data[clazz] = clazz(*args, **kwargs)


class A:
    def method_of_a(self):
        pass


s = Service()
s.register(A)

x = s.get(A)
x.method_of_a()
reveal_type(x)
```

When run with `mypy`, the `reveal_type()` call prints out

```
so73566368.py:24: note: Revealed type is "so73566368.A"
```